# How to use viewport to make the mobile devices scale to the width of the content?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I'm writing a book reader in which a book can be of variable width, for example, it could be 1028px or it could be 2000px or 560px width.

I'd like mobile devices to scale automatically so that when they're viewing the book it will scale the book to always be the width of the screen.

What I'm currently doing is... (example book has 1028px width & 1648px height)

In the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1028"/>
```

In the stylesheet:

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
.bz { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:none; width:1028px; }
.pz { width:1028px; height:1648px; position:relative; }
```

And the body is in the form of:

```
<div class="bz">
   <div class="pz">
     Page 1 content
   </div>
   <div class="pz">
     Page 2 content
   </div>
   <div class="pz">
     Page 3 content
   </div>
</div>
```

This stacks the pages vertically, which works... except there are two problems:

1. On mobile device the content doesn't actually fit perfectly on the screen, it needs a little horizontal scroll to view all of it. So basically it's not zoomed perfectly to the width of the device screen.
2. On mobile device there is loads of white space on the right, the horizontal scrollbar is present and it allows the user to scroll really far to the right into loads of white space. This doesn't occur on the desktop browser which correctly disables the horizontal scroll if the browser window is larger than the content width.

I must be doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

wrong approach in my opinion.

the best practice for anything reponsive is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

if you want to adjust the readability of the content, you should think about font-size, not screen-size or "container" size.

you could use `em` units or `rem` units and adjust the relative size of your whole reading experience changing one simple value: `font-size` in `body`.

by default 1em = 16px = 100% - so you can start with:

```
body {
    font-size:100%
}
```

through javascript you can change that value to bigger or smaller and your whole content font-size will scale accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but these are fixed-layout pages consisting of multiple media types, not simple text pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

instead of this..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1028"/>
```

> I'd like mobile devices to scale automatically so that when they're
>   viewing the book it will scale the book to always be the width of the
>   screen.

If you want the width to respond to screen width remove `width:1028px;` from your css. Currently it's saying to always be that wide, never wider and never narrower.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Exactly that size, never wide and never narrower. I don't want the width the respond to the screen, I want the screen to respond to the width.

Comment: That's clearly not possible if the screen has less than 1028 pixels. Content scales to screens..not the other way round.